# Get last value in a column not equal to some value

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2019

I have an excel spreadsheet with a column with states where I have ran races. I would like to write a function that returns the last out of state race I ran. How would I do that?

Comment: Use Lookup? Something along the lines of `=LOOKUP(2,1/(A:A<>"State"),A:A)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `INDEX()` to get the
row number:

```
=INDEX(MAX((A:A<>"")*(A:A<>"NJ")*(ROW(A:A))),0)
```

[image]

and `INDEX()` to get the value:

```
=INDEX(A:A,INDEX(MAX(($A:$A<>"")*(A:A<>"NJ")*(ROW(A:A))),0))
```

for the last value not equal to *NJ*.

Comment: Thanks @Gary's Student! That worked! Now I am trying to get the corresponding date ad I am using index match to do so. When I do that, it shows the first time I ran in the state, not the last time. Any idea why?